# Rename x rows after value in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas Dataframe containing a time series of data.
Every full second contains a string with the name of the point. I want to rename the next 4 values, that contain a random point id, after this row to the name of the first row with an added suffix

```
time ID
12:00:00,00 pointname1
12:00:00,20 12345
12:00:00,40 45645
12:00:00,60 78963
12:00:00,80 23432
12:00:01,00 pointname2
12:00:01,20 53454
12:00:01,40 24324
12:00:01,60 24324
12:00:01,80 42435
```

I want to transform this into:

```
time ID
12:00:00,00 pointname1
12:00:00,20 pointname1_1
12:00:00,40 pointname1_2
12:00:00,60 pointname1_3
12:00:00,80 pointname1_4
12:00:01,00 pointname2
12:00:01,20 pointname2_1
12:00:01,40 pointname2_2
12:00:01,60 pointname2_3
12:00:01,80 pointname2_4
```

I have a working solution by iterating over the entire DataFrame, detecting the 'pointname' rows and renaming the 4 rows after that. However, that takes a very long time with the 1.3million rows the data contains. Is there a more clever and efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for set missing values to not matched values and then forward filling them, last use counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and add values without first:

```
df['ID'] = df['ID'].where(df['ID'].str.startswith('pointname')).ffill()
df['ID'] +=  df.groupby('ID').cumcount().astype(str).radd('_').replace('_0','')

print (df)
          time            ID
0  12:00:00,00    pointname1
1  12:00:00,20  pointname1_1
2  12:00:00,40  pointname1_2
3  12:00:00,60  pointname1_3
4  12:00:00,80  pointname1_4
5  12:00:01,00    pointname2
6  12:00:01,20  pointname2_1
7  12:00:01,40  pointname2_2
8  12:00:01,60  pointname2_3
9  12:00:01,80  pointname2_4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) (or [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) if your identifier is literal, the only important point is to have `True` for the rows to use as referenc) to identify the ID rows, then for all other rows use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) and [`groupby.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to make the new identifier:

```
# find rows with string identifier (could use other methods)
m = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors='coerce').isna()
# or if "pointname" is literal
# m = df['ID'].str.startswith('pointname') 


# for non matching rows, use previous value
# and add group counter
df.loc[~m, 'ID'] = (df['ID'].where(m).ffill()
                    +'_'
                    +df.groupby(m.cumsum()).cumcount().astype(str)
                   )
```

output:

```
          time            ID
0  12:00:00,00    pointname1
1  12:00:00,20  pointname1_1
2  12:00:00,40  pointname1_2
3  12:00:00,60  pointname1_3
4  12:00:00,80  pointname1_4
5  12:00:01,00    pointname2
6  12:00:01,20  pointname2_1
7  12:00:01,40  pointname2_2
8  12:00:01,60  pointname2_3
9  12:00:01,80  pointname2_4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby` the `time` part of `time` column and `transform` `ID` column to add suffix to first value in each group.

```py
df['ID'] = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            ['ID'].transform(lambda col: [f'{col.iloc[0]}_{s}' for s in ['']+list(range(1, len(col)))])
            .str.rstrip('_'))
# or
df['ID'] = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
            ['ID'].transform(lambda col: [col.iloc[0]] + [f'{col.iloc[0]}_{s}' for s in range(1, len(col))]))
```

```
print(df)

          time            ID
0  12:00:00,00    pointname1
1  12:00:00,20  pointname1_1
2  12:00:00,40  pointname1_2
3  12:00:00,60  pointname1_3
4  12:00:00,80  pointname1_4
5  12:00:01,00    pointname2
6  12:00:01,20  pointname2_1
7  12:00:01,40  pointname2_2
8  12:00:01,60  pointname2_3
9  12:00:01,80  pointname2_4
```